# Confidence interval for prediction

Tags: statistical-inference

If we have the following linear model for the response $y_i$, how does one compute a confidance intervall for the expected value of $y_i$?

[image]

Comment: där?${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @joriki "where" sorry